# Should moderators be able to delete answers on questions they answer themselves?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, moderators

Pretend someone answers a question with what they feel is a valid answer. Currently, a moderator could delete that answer and immediately post their own. If the original answer writer were to flag their deleted answer to be reopened, by the time it is addressed all the attention / votes will have gone to the moderator's answer.

I'm sure the moderators' intentions are always pure, but it seems potentially unfair for a moderator to be able to delete an answer without review and immediately post their own answer. It might be more difficult for a moderator to remain entirely impartial if they know deleting a questionable answer could benefit them. Would a moderator be more likely, even subconsciously, to delete an answer they might otherwise only down vote if they know their own answer would benefit from the visibility?

Should there be some separation to prevent a situation where a moderator could potentially be inclined to delete an answer so that their own answer gets more visibility? Maybe moderators forfeit reputation on answers to questions they have interacted with using moderator privileges?

Comment: Was the answer practicly the same (also a Don't Do it answer) or completely different?

Comment: @AndréKool: see my answer below. I'd be happy to link to the post in question, if that'd help.

Comment: There have been a few (only a few, but certainly more than two or three) instances in which I handled a flag from the queue by deleting an answer, old or new, to a question that I forgot I answered years ago and wasn't recorded in my browsing history. And sometimes I only realize it the next time I visit the question, which may be weeks, months, or years later, or when a different moderator stumbles upon it and informs me. It's a little awkward when either happens.

Comment: I for one would appreciate if the mod tools would warn me that I've answered a question I'm about to handle a flag on and allow me to cancel. That doesn't really address the problem of being able to delete posts where no flag was involved, though.

Comment: @AndréKool I did not mean to make a case for any specific incident and updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Not to discredit this idea, but moderators typically all have 20k+ rep (and then some) and I'm pretty certain rep stops meaning much at that point. I highly doubt anyone with that much rep would care if they got a post with 5 score and accepted, as they were probably already at the rep cap anyway

Comment: Have you experienced this before or is this just a hypothetical question?

Comment: @TylerH Hypothetical

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Moderators are not allowed to remove valid content *period*; I don't see why the rule needs to be any more complicated than that.

I've deleted spam answers that were left on questions that I asked years ago without concern for conflicting interests. I've removed non answers from questions where I've also answered without concern for conflicting interests, as these 'answers' were either flat out jokes or just clueless people 'having the same problem'.

I don't see a need to make it any more complicated. All deleted content is still visible to the person that wrote it, or anyone with over 10k reputation, so it's not like this could happen in the middle of the night in some kind of underhanded way.

Moderators have a tough enough job; I'm not going to make it harder on them unless there's a *clear* abuse case that needs to be addressed. To date, there hasn't been one :)

Comment: "in the middle of the night" ? with all those new Aussie mods :) ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Precisely, I mean who _knows_ what could happen when they're sleeping?

Comment: "All deleted content is still visible to the person that wrote it, or anyone with over 10k reputation" Well, if two moderators were in cahoots, I suppose they could redact a revision to hide who deleted it, I suppose, but AFAIK there's no precedent for such an underhanded thing among our moderators (luckily) and employees would still be able to tell what happened.

Comment: @TylerH Precisely. If we ever got to that point, then we'll have reached an intersection where the exception is _way_ out of the realm of what software should be handling, it becomes a human issue then. Fortunately we've never come close to anything like that, the worst we've ever seen was two mods zapping each other in full public view and that was, well, not hidden :) I think we've found a good place where we can pretty safely say anything above this is so unlikely to ever happen that it's not worth considering in code.

Comment: A rule which is good when it is not abused is a ___ rule when no abuse is expected.

Answer (score 30):

A moderator should never handle flags or posts where there could be a conflict of interest, no. We have plenty of active moderators we can ask to look into issues were we might not be entirely impartial.

That wasn't the case with your specific post however. You *didn't post an answer*, you posted a non-constructive link to another post, ignoring the actual question.

> I answered a question with what I felt was a valid "Don't Do it" answer.

No, you did not. You posted:

> > This regex matches any html code.
>
> [You cannot parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9478968)

to a question that didn't even ask for a way to parse HTML with a regex. They were asking why a regex they found was producing a parser error, with Python. That's not a *don't do it* answer, that's commentary on a single remark made in the question to frame their actual problem.

That that regex was intended to extract data from HTML had nothing to do with the actual problem they faced.

The post was

1. unhelpful, it didn't address the question.
2. link-only, as the explanation was elsewhere.
3. linking to a great piece of art, but that too is not actually an answer to the question posted.
4. should just have been left as a comment.

> Within a minute or so a moderator deleted my answer and posted their own.

You make it sound as if I only posted an answer after I deleted your post. You posted that answer 2 minutes after mine (which, in turn came minutes after I confirmed in the comments on the question that there was an actual solution), and I deleted your post another 2 minutes later with a comment:

> However much I'm a fan of that post, this is not an answer to the question. Use a comment next time.

Don't post glib remarks to joke posts. Especially not when they are not addressing the question.

Had there been an actual answer on the post that could possibly be seen as competing with an answer of mine, I *always* ask another moderator to handle any issues. I didn't see the point here, however. I'm also abstaining from handling the flag you cast on your answer to have it undeleted again.

Comment: I am not saying you did anything wrong. I flagged because I thought it counted as a "Don't Do it" answer but wasn't sure and was waiting for clarification in the flag response. I did not make a separate post here on meta calling attention to it. I posed the question here as a more general case. Had I thought there was any wrong doing I would have posted it as it's own topic with specifics.

Comment: No need to be acrimonious. This was a general question. The answer to the general question is flag and move on. While this answer might be "right" and "great for OP", it's not useful to the wider community.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode: then it'd be helpful if you edited your question to make it generic; your specific example is not applicable here.

Comment: I was hoping to handle this via the flag but since you are here, `This regex matches any html code.` was a quote from the asker's question. Both of the strings he was testing his regex on were html. I agree that I did not answer his question about why his regex was not working, but I was advising that the asker not use regex to parse html. I could understand deleting for `link-only, as the explanation was elsewhere.`, but if I edited to include more explanation from the linked post would it be ok?

Comment: @ConfusedByCode: No, it wouldn't be ok because it doesn't answer the question at all. If you already have an answer that solves all the problems in the question, than an additional remark to not parse HTML with regex is fine. If you just want to leave an additional remark, then add a comment.

Comment: @BDL that makes sense. I actually added it as a comment first, but then googled if it was ok to add an answer warning people not to do something. I read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8893) answer and thought it might be better to post as an answer.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode: If op asks something along the line of "I'm trying to parse HTML code with a Regex but it doesn't work", then such an answer would be fine. But from what I read here, op asked not specifically about HTML parsing (although the example did regex-HTML parsing) but about a more general problem with Regex. In this case, answer the question (because it is valid and might help others in future who don't do HTML parsing) and leave a remark about the HTML thing.

Comment: @BDL Yeah I think I understand the distinction now. Had the question been about parsing HTML with regex a warning might have been an appropriate answer. But because the question only heavily implied that the asker intends on parsing HTML with regex a warning belongs in a comment to the asker?

Comment: @ConfusedByCode In my opinion: Correct.

Answer (score 10):

Moderators are also subject to moderation. Moderators should be careful to make sure they have no personal interest in their actions:

- If a post or comment is flagged, it should be handled by a disinterested moderator.
- Likewise, a moderator should not delete an answer and post a similar 
  one themselves.

The correct action is to flag the answer, explaining the situation, and the issue should be handled by a different moderator.

Answer (score 4):

A moderator **should** be able to delete answers disregarding if they are answering the same question or not.

If an answer is plagiarized, for example, the fact that they are answering is not relevant to deleting the plagiarized answer.

*Preventing them to act on a raised flag* just because they have answered a question doesn't seem useful or practical.

*Blocking them from answering* because they acted on a flag on an answer, neither.

If you believe your answer was deleted in error, just re-flag explaining the fact. Some other moderator will take a look at it.

Or even bring it up in here meta, hopefully with a link to your deleted answer (and a screenshot for us low-rep users), where it could get additional exposure and scrutiny.

There are very few moderators (and many users, many questions, many answers). The need to curate content is very strong. Making a blanket rule making curation harder would be counter-productive.

Moderators being so few, it's easy to act on potential cases of abuse or error of judgment individually. **If you believe you've encountered something like this, just report it, either via flag or here in meta with all the pertinent information**

Comment: I could see why preventing answering/deleting is bad, but the current system still seems less than ideal. Maybe moderators could still answer questions but would forfeit any reputation gain if they used moderator privileges to delete another answer.

Comment: @ConfusedByCode, there's already a function for this, there's a box for "community wiki" when you answer. If this is checked, then no credit goes to the author.