# What examples are there for Not Being Very Welcoming?

Tags: discussion, welcoming

> **It was hard to accept some of the (valid) criticism, especially the idea that women and people of color felt particularly unwelcome.**
>
> [..]
>
> Many people, especially those in marginalized groups *do* feel less welcome. *We know because they tell us.*
>                      <sub>— https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change</sub>

For the purposes of a constructive discussion on solving this problem, can we have some concrete examples of how this manifests? I feel that dealing in generalities (e.g. "biases") doesn't really help here, since either the general idea is rejected outright (e.g. "I'm not biased!", "Bias studies don't work."), or everyone interprets the meaning of those generalities differently and we end up discussing different things. On the other hand, we could probably all agree on specific instances of such issues if presented with some.

Are we talking about:

- Minority groups being treated *statistically more unfair* than other groups? E.g., more of their questions are getting closed and/or downvoted at the same level of quality?
- Minority groups experiencing specific *slurs* or other direct *attacks*?
- Minority groups *feeling generally less secure* about participating in the system as it exists because of their background; in this case, what specifically about Stack Overflow's default modus operandi is troubling to them?
- Anything else I'm not thinking of?

<sub>(Please anonymise specific examples as appropriate. Provide enough context so the example can be judged on its own merits as a fully formed data point.)</sub>

Comment: Shog9 [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366648/1835379) a related question with a bunch of links. That'll probably fill your _"plural anecdote"_ quota.

Comment: @Cerbrus, but I believe those links are about newcomers experiences. I think that deceze is asking about minority groups experiences specifically.

Comment: Problem with people belonging to "minority" groups is that the second something bad happens they will instantly jump to the conclusion it is because they belong to some minority group. I have been in tech for almost 30 years and nothing bad ever happened to me because of my gender. I don't think SO has any problems with minorities, only with enormous amounts of bad and low quality questions posted by all kinds of people...

Comment: It is hard to imagine being able to answer "do you have statistical proof to say minority groups are being treated more unfair" while the answer to "do you have any data" is "we don't know".

Comment: I had a package delivery guy park in front of the shared parking space, blocking 16 people from leaving their home. I asked in a friendly tone if he would move the truck two meters and not block the packing space the next time. Immediately he said I was a racist, because I 'attacked' him. The clue of the story is similar to @DalijaPrasnikar: if you belong to a minority group, you might feel offended and immediately think it is because of your race/color/etc. Sometimes it is just that you asked a bad question, or parked in a inconvenient place.

Comment: Side note: I’ll point out that I’m not a fan of the term “minorities” in this context, since women and people of color certainly aren’t a minority world-wide, and SO is an international thing. I just use this term here for brevity, and because some groups *are* in the minority on SO.

Comment: @ayhan The "we don't know" is from community members, not a CM.

Comment: @ayhan, Patrick: Hence this question. Let’s talk about specifics as much as possible without jumping to general conclusions either way…

Comment: I would love to see statistics too @deceze. It is hard to discuss this topic since all we have is opinions now.

Comment: @deceze Yep, minorities is not the best term...

Comment: While SO tries to be "an international thing", the blog post and the discussion around it are very US centric. The whole idea of minorities and them being mistreated on platforms like SO is very strange to somebody like me living in a, as I hope, civilized country lilke Germany. That's not because there are no minorities here, there are. And not every person is always treated as good as he/she/it deserves. But the self blaming that seems to be en vouge in the US is very irritating to me.

Comment: You won't get a MCVE, because it's stock standard radical leftist virtue signalling, thrown in for good measure. The author, like much of Silicon Valley and American tech, suffers from cultural Marxism, a worldview that consists of only the oppressor and the oppressed. The fact that the oppression is imaginary doesn't matter.

Comment: @nmit026 Let’s try to postpone such conclusions for a while. If there’s nothing but tumbleweeds for a few days here, then would be the right time to conclude that.

Comment: Since the blog post, there is only one minority group for which any examples of hostile bias and abuse has been demonstrated by multiple exampes.  That is, actual examples, not 'implicit' feelings or stories.  That would be the set of SO volunteer user-moderators.

Comment: Maybe a different way to phrase this question would be: *Everyone talks about there being a fire. Please, show me the fire.*

Comment: Here is an example of how "they tell us": https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52

Comment: @Evk Thank you for that link, that post does contain some useful examples. I'll probably extract some of them to post as answer here.

Comment: @deceze well I consider this post a bunch of nonsense, but I'm glad you were able to find some useful examples there. In any case, that's certainly an example of "people tell us", and I even think SO blog post in question was largely inspired by post I linked, at least certain parts of it.

Comment: @deceze That will be an useful answer. Outside views are relevant because, if we indeed have a problem, any attempt to collect examples from Meta denizens like you and me will be strongly affected by selection bias.

Comment: @Evk It's at least something concrete to talk about. Yes, some of those points I clearly see "the other side" too and don't see much that could change, but other examples I do agree with. Presented below without specific comments…

Comment: @deceze Should this be tagged support rather than discussion since it is asking for an official company response of data?

Comment: My take is: Stack Overflow is equally rude and unwelcoming to everyone. People with a lot of privilege (like me) have no problem pushing past that. People without don't have the spare mental energy, and give up, or go anonymous. I only know one female dev in real life who posts here with a female sounding name. A few others post with non-gendered handles. Most that I have asked operate strictly in read-only mode.

Comment: Frankly, I find it very hard to be more unwelcoming to dogs, women or anyone else. For all I know I could be arguing with a squirrel. It's called the internet.

Comment: SO can come over as rude. Case in point a guy yesterday as an account "Robert" he posted his homework with 4 lines saying make it.. to which he got flamed down.. So he then made a new account Rob, copied a small bit of code he had written and all his previous question slightly edited again.. Problem was enough people spotted it was the same and closed it down.  (Oddly as spam!) i know Ive felt tetchy with people when you ask questions and their responses "Just give me the answer".. when you needed more info, or you ask them things they dont answer.. its not always easy to be calm and kind.

Comment: @Bug Yes, if this was a smaller community and *everyone* behaved nicely we wouldn't have this discussion. It *is* difficult to always take the moral highroad when some people just don't care and blatantly abuse the system.

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹIm female ! I chose bugfinder so people dont judge by boobs but quality of content

Comment: @Bug Did you make that choice *after* experiencing specific boob judgement on SO, or preemptively, perhaps due to previous experience elsewhere ("in the world" I suppose?)?

Comment: @deceze as an older fart in the world, while others have pointed out no one knows for sure who/what is behind any account posting. I have found as a whole theres still enough people out there who wouldnt take an answer from a woman.. but would if they couldnt tell, why not just be genderless and have people assume Im male.

Comment: @Bug We're starting to tug at the very fabric of society here… Whatever SO management will implement to fix all this, it better be good. :D

Comment: @deceze Would it be appropriate to put something about minorities into the title of the question e.g. "MCVE for Not Being Very Welcoming to Under-represented Groups" or "MCVE for Not Being Very Welcoming to Specific Groups". Some answers are just about people feeling unwelcomed in general, which is true, and should probably be improved, but is not the subject of this question.

Comment: @rjmunro The title is supposed to generically refer to The Blog Post™. I'm of two minds whether to make it more specific or not, especially since the entire thing is apparently easy to be misinterpreted as being about discrimination, which apparently it's not.

Comment: I think this case is also a good example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364891/reasonable-suggested-edit-but-inappropriate-edit-summary

Comment: @deceze I think the staff are in two minds about whether the post is about discrimination (*most* of it seems to be open to interpretation either way, but if it's not meant to be about discrimination, then what's all the stuff about "bias" doing there?), so *you* being in two minds can be easily forgiven.

Comment: It was a different discussion, but I [wrote about my experience on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281304/426671) 4 years ago. That's just a small glimpse about what I experienced on the site. It's also a bit of what happens to users.

Comment: @deceze I suggest leaving the title as it is, precisely for the reason you point out.

Comment: @Taryn I was just about to upvote that post after reading it when I saw that I had already upvoted it… Some time ago apparently. 

Comment: @deceze That's what happens when these conversations have been going on for years. :P

Comment: Here's a related question on Meta.SE with many more concrete examples: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309513/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-especially-marginalized-groups

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ: While rudeness might be equal opportunity on SO (although I fail to see why misogyny should be any less ingrained here than elsewhere in society), the userbase is still predominantly male, so that rudeness will also be of a predominantly male sort. It isn't a great leap to imagine that, although nominally equal, the rudeness will be affecting men and women differently.

Comment: From blog: " It makes me sad when someone get downvoted for posting a duplicate." There is nothing sad about it. If they did not find dup themselves then community, which is much more familiar with this site, will do it. There is nothing sad about it. People should grow thicker skin and not overthink other peoples' comments.

Comment: @AkselA Heh, hadn't even considered gendered rudeness. Also wanted to point out though that we should distinguish between: generic rudeness that disproportionately affects less privileged groups (as I referred to), bias (mostly unconscious, eg, women's answers being challenged more than men's), and the much less common case of overt sexism/racism/etc. Much of the indignant response to the blog post seems to be defending against accusations of overt sexism/racism - whereas the other two categories are much more widespread, I'd wager.

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ: I agree. Unintentional discrimination is by far more common than overt, and is for a variety of reasons more difficult to deal with. Chances are that even well meaning individuals, like myself, partake in it. It is a sort of ignorance, or lack of insight, and dealing with that is difficult. Calling out individuals for transgressions on a case by case basis, as I see some argue for, can just as easily increase hostility. What we need is a systemic response to a systemic problem.

Comment: @AlexL Well, what the blog author doesn't take into account is that most duplicate are poorly written (out of search knowledge), and are downvoted as such, badly written posts. There's probably a bunch of people disliking to close as dupe and downvoting regardless of the post quality that said and this should be addressed also as dupe are signposts to the correct answers. So I may understand mixed feelings for blind downvote and close as dupe, but I still don't find the sentence you quoted helping the overall goal.

Comment: The comment section of my article [The decline of Stack Overflow](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) provides ample examples! I referenced a couple of them [over here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366937/is-stack-overflow-really-racist-sexist/367131#367131).

Comment: Not sure where I just found it but https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2413303 explains well that research is expected before asking on SO.

Comment: Is there a way to see if a person belonging to a particular account is a woman? Is it possible that I have missed the pink background that is present on every female account link? Because how can I treat women differently if I have no way to find out if a particular account belongs to a man or a woman?

Comment: This is like asking "How can the country club be exclusionary to poor people? Everyone pays the same $10,000 entry fee". The same behavior applied to someone in a dominant group can have very different results when applied to someone in a non-dominant group.

Comment: Best meta-post of 2018, maybe. I wanted so badly to ask a question like this. Congrats to OP!

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: well.. you don't have an example, have you? how can you know I'm a man? Do you want to say men=rich, women=poor? That's bias :-D

Comment: Some of these comments are frickin' hilarious.Cluelessness on such a scale is truly amazing. Framing everything in terms of right-wing/left wing buzzwords is part of the problem.

Comment: My 2 cents: We are quite sure, that there is a gender-bias (or sex-bias) on SO and maybe even on other collaborative online places (such as Wikipedia), because that's what statistics tell us. However, how minorities FEEL only gets communicated via surveys, which are anything then objective. My point is: I treat everybody the same, because we are mostly anonymous here, unless a concious decision leads me to change that (e.g. on my profile, my username etc.). So, how could I even tell, which minority, ethnical group, sexual identity or such I am oppressing?

Comment: As a minority myself, I never felt discriminated. When moderators want to be condescending, they are condescending to everyone equally!

Comment: @LutzHorn Germany just legalized gay marriage less than a year ago. There have been several recent arson attacks against mosques and refugee centers. Turkish and Roma people are discriminated against. Is Germany as "civilized" as you say?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser What about the "Ehe für alle", as same sex marriage is called in Germany, is not civilized?

Comment: @LutzHorn The lack of it until just recently.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser Just to continue this plain off-topic discussion. Please name a country that is civilized by this standard.

Comment: @LutzHorn I'd move this to chat if I could. But my point was that your idea of "civilized" is flawed. Bigotry exists worldwide, and pretending Germany is too good to have bigots is silly.

Comment: sounds like gamers are going to rise up, but ok

Comment: Historically locking posts that are useless

Answer (score 66):

To me, the blog post seemed to be referring pretty clearly to marginalized groups being statistically more likely to say they didn't feel welcome to the question about what adjectives they associated with Stack Overflow on the 2018 survey. That's how I'm interpreting the "We know because they tell us" in the block you posted.

I have a close female colleague who uses Stack Overflow as minimally as possible and when asked why, one of the major stories she tells is that she once edited a post in response to comments, only to be attacked for using appeasing wording when she did so. This is a basic [gender difference in communication](https://www.forbes.com/sites/carolkinseygoman/2016/03/31/is-your-communication-style-dictated-by-your-gender/#7831cf43eb9d):

> In all cases, a communication style turns into a weakness when overdone. A female’s collaborative approach can come across submissive and a male’s directness can be taken as callousness. Men come across as too aggressive when their expansive postures infringe on other people’s personal space, when they have a “death grip” handshake, and when they emphasize status cues to the point where look haughty and uncaring. Women are viewed as weak or passive when they are unnecessarily apologetic, when they smile excessively or inappropriately, and when they discount their own ideas and achievements.

The man verbally attacking my colleague clearly interpreted what she intended as warmth and deference to expertise as excessive weakness/submission and was irritated by that. Whereas a lot of the men who come across as callous and aggressive on Stack Overflow see themselves as being direct and to-the-point. **And they're not wrong.** They're just judging themselves by a different meterstick than people who aren't comfortable on Stack Overflow use to judge how they're being treated.

There are core values/functions at the root of these different communication styles: maintaining and building relationships vs. focusing exclusively on objective/logical/external problems. Because Stack Overflow has historically classified communication whose function is to address relationship concerns between the posters as being "noise" whereas purely technical answers are "signal", it's created a situation where these 2 values are pitted against each other. The blog post announces a change where they're trying to make these 2 values work together instead:

> Let’s reject the false dichotomy between quality and kindness. Quality
> matters because it means posts can help more people. But a larger,
> more diverse community produces better artifacts, not worse ones. We
> need to stop justifying condescension with the pursuit of quality, and
> we need better tools and queues to help power users trying to keep
> quality high.

I believe the basic values/communication style conflict here can occur on a cross-cultural level, not just a cross-gender level.

Comment: Wow if that's the case the blog author was not very clear...

Comment: Definitely there are gender differences in communication. But let's remember that physical presence and body language are irrelevant when we're all just a name and thumbnail typing words into little boxes on a screen to another name and thumbnail. I found SO unwelcoming at first, but that was because of the way I was trying to use it (I had the vague idea it was like a chat forum, or something). It takes a while to get used to it. I still can't believe that there is such a huge community of people that will answer your (clear and specific) questions, well, for free. It's a two-way street.

Comment: @Adair: "*Because StackOverflow has historically classified communication whose function is to address relationship concerns between the posters as being "noise" whereas purely technical answers are "signal", it's created a situation where these 2 values are pitted against each other.*" OK, but... that's what SO *is for*. So exists to create a database of knowledge. "Relationship concerns" don't appear in textbooks and reference manuals, so they should not appear here. There's no way to have both a database of knowledge *and* "relationship concerns".

Comment: The question asked for concrete examples. This does not seem to provide an MCVE. That looks more like an extended comment on the blog post.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The second paragraph introduces a concrete example.

Comment: @duplode I think this answer would address the question better if it actually showed what the "appeasing wording" looked like, and what exactly is meant by being "attacked".

Comment: @rogerdpack of course not. It's not in their interest to be clear.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: have you ever seen how "we are all so biased" people provide concrete (or verifyable) examples?

Comment: @Michael Your question seems somewhat rhetorical and suggestive. I cannot claim that I've ever actively searched for evidence presented by the "we are all so biased"-people, or that I've studied in any detail what they have to say, so I can't give you any meaningful answer. But I have to admit that I'm not impressed by the "evidence" presented in this thread so far. Especially stuff like *"words 'exactly' and especially 'clearly' are warning signs"* in the other answer -- what? This is "rude"? What does it have to do with women or people of color?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: yes, it probably is rhetorical. Thing is, I have tried to search for these things but couldn't find it. Sure, sexism is happening, but I cannot understand such things as "implicit bias". But I know a good way to drive people to insanity: make some accusations, but don't provide any concrete examples; don't say anything that would be falsifiable, so people will have a hard time to respond meaningfully to your claims. I'm accusing the "we are all so biased" people of intellectual dishonesty.

Comment: @Michael I can kind-of empathize with what you are saying, but still, it doesn't seem really constructive. The "'we are all so biased'-people" seems like a very vague description of a huge inhomogeneous group of people. The "intellectual dishonesty" part is a rather serious accusation, just like "sexism", and your comment also doesn't quite seem to contain enough evidence to back up this claim. This just heats the debate even more. I don't blame anyone, I just think that it's a complex topic that is known to generate heat and debates, and IMHO should be completely off-topic on SO.

Comment: Prior to the recent blog kerfuffle, I recently suggested the idea that [deferential language in questions might contribute to their poor reception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions). One of the answers, with a graph, shows that this might be correct. The state of that question is now: (1) how can we measure this, and (2) is it best to try to modify this in the UI (filter language that gets into questions) or culturally (ask readers to be more tolerant). I favour the former, as I think it's easier to achieve.

Comment: If I read a self help book, "Programmers Guide to Java" or something a long those lines, should I immediately get upset when the book get's to the point without being apologetic about it?

Comment: @Nicol:

_"..that's what SO is for [reducing "noise" in technical information]. SO exists to create..knowledge. 'Relationship concerns' don't appear in textbooks..so they should not appear here. There's no way to have both..'"_

Why don't you think those two things can coexist in the same corpus of knowledge? And why do you think that SO should necessarily mimic a property of textbooks, which presumably should lack relationship concerns?

SO can be anything. It's far more than a read-only textbook. It's writable, and intrinsically social. The social aspect often sucks, and it shouldn't.

Comment: @AlexHall: "*And why do you think that SO should necessarily mimic a property of textbooks, which presumably should lack relationship concerns?*" If SO's purpose is to create knowledge, "relationship concerns" aren't part of that. Remember: our primary goal is to serve neither the asker or the answerer; we serve the third person, who is looking for a solution to the problem and finds it here. That person *does not care* about "relationship concerns" between the first two people. They care about getting the solution; why should they have to deal with irrelevant things to get that?

Comment: @Nicol Are you seriously speaking on behalf of all visitors to SO and asserting that they don't care about this issue? Do you really want to do that?

I will tell you that you _do not_ speak for my perspective on this. I care about this a great deal. I do not care one whit for a knowledge building community that is inhumane. (Actually, I care a lot; it bothers me that it is often inhumane: it rubs against this core tenet I have: be humane.) 

There isn't any controversy over the fact that SO is too often inhumane. The controversy is that too many people don't care about that fact.

Comment: @AlexHall: So, it's now "inhumane" not to use "hello" and "thank you"? Sorry; not buying it. These words are pleasantries, but not using them is hardly equivalent to punching someone in the face.

Comment: @AlexHall Do encyclopedias have pleasantries?  Do dictionaries?  All along, *that's* what SE's goal has been; cut out the noise, to get at the signal.  Pleasantries detract from that goal, and that's why things like please and thanks get removed.

Comment: To the two most previous commentors: surface mechanics of language are not the substance of the issue here. You are missing the point.

Comment: Active hostility is the substance of the issue. In the example here, the experience of a woman who was _censured_ by SO users for putting appeasing language or pleasantries in an answer.

The issue at hand is _being a jerk_ about SO rules. We can enforce rules without being jerks. Or, I hope we can. SO repeatedly disappoints that hope.

I think whether the rules _enable us to be jerks_ or even verily _lead us to be jerks_ is also part of the issue.

Comment: The 22 people who upvoted Nicol's answer also are missing the point. At this writing, the second most-upvoted comment here. Which is another reason I despair for SO culture.

Answer (score 48):

I do not know how the statistical data was collected and end up to saying **"women and people of color"**.

When you say people of color do you mean like me? Black!! So far as I can remember I have never experienced any struggle or hardness in using Stack Overflow due to my color or being African. Maybe being jobless for not qualifying for a lot of native Android remote jobs, but I do not have proof that it is related to my color either.

The data may be categorized in a bad fashion, I think the problem is simply *English*. People of color, as you have named them, always come from a non-English speaking country. And this is evident when you are reviewing the post from new users.

For instance me, English is my third language, and so many other people, mainly African and Asians, have English as a second or third language. So structuring a question in fluent English can be tricky (plus not knowing Stack Overflow rules).

And by the way, many new users do not even upload their pics on their first days; how will you know their color so as to start the discrimination?

The data may be accurate, but the reason may not be **people of color**!

Comment: "People of color as you have named them, they always come from a Non-English speaking country" This is categorically not true; there are millions of people of color (possibly billions)  born and raised in countries where English is taught as a first language.

Comment: Yeah, that is some really clunky phrasing. The problem is likely English cultural conventions as they pertain to the tech world, and that's not a community a lot of people have direct exposure to. Working on fixing the culture by pointing out problems and leading by example is the only way to fix this in the long term.

Comment: So you really think people click to View others profile picture, so as to check their colors and then start discriminating them, And new users mainly do not even upload profile pictures. All in all english can be not the only reason but people in SO do not check profile pictures so as to start downvoting @TylerH

Comment: @Xenolion I don't see how your comment is at all related to what I said... did you mean to reply to tadman instead?

Comment: Sure @tadman its more of a cultural issues.

Comment: The comment was yours. I know there may be black people in USA, Indians in England etc but majority of them are not there. @TylerH

Comment: *"When you say people of color do you mean like me? Black!!"* - We can't really be sure whether this was the intended meaning, since whether the term "people of color" should refer to all non-whites or specifically to blacks is a bitter culture-war question within the American feminist movement (see e.g. http://www.dukechronicle.com/article/2017/09/are-asians-people-of-color). For that reason, I've stuck to just referring to "people of color" in scare quotes when discussing Jay's blog post - I don't know who he means, and posting a Meta question to ask isn't worth the time or drama.

Comment: @Xenolion I said nothing about judging people by looking at profile pictures, I simply said there are people of color from English-speaking countries.

Comment: I have got you now @TylerH I did not get it the first time.

Comment: The apartheid regime considered the Japanese as white but not the Chinese (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorary_whites). The "people of color"/"african american" expressions used on the US feel really weird from the outside. Oh, and if you're African, the political correct term is Afro African :D

Comment: I have never heard of "Afro African" before, well then I like it. @brasofilo

Answer (score 35):

A random splattering of examples.

**The precise wording may be different, but the meaning is the same.**

> We shouldn't be like Bangladeshi call centre workers on SO. This
>   doesn't work.
>
> Speaking with these 2 groups is like being in Syria. You're much
>   better off with group 3 where there's less religion.
>
> There are several ways to say "of course not!" It is not clear which
>   way you prefer.
>
> Do yourself and the [tag] community a favor and do find out why X is so bad.

What makes these kinds of comments more disturbing:

1. They are often written by valued members of the community with 100k+ rep.
2. They often attract upvotes, whether +10 or +50. Although this is uncontrollable, it *matters* because this is what gets emphasized when a reader first sees a post.
3. When not explicitly rude, they resort to sarcasm which is much harder to moderate.

These are cherry picked, but let's be clear: I am as much concerned about the **hundreds of upvotes** these comments accrue before they are removed. Yes, comments cannot be downvoted, but it's equally true none of the upvoters flagged for moderator attention.

A user enters a chat room, [asks for a disturbing conversation to stop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366793/9209546) and gets into an argument with the regulars.

A user asks a [genuine question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365636/9209546), gets an [aggressive answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365643/9209546), and subsequently leaves SO.

A user asks a [genuine question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366049/9209546), gets a [sarcastic answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366050/9209546) (see the edit disagreement on that answer), and hasn't been seen since.

**Disclosure:** I posted answers to the last two questions myself, reflecting what I believe are *useful* responses to the questions posed. So I do believe there are alternatives.

I can append to this again and again. The bottom line is these users aren't unhappy *just* because they are wrong and fail to admit it (which may well be the truth), but because they are **made to feel unwelcome**.

I'm sure someone will come in and try and justify each of these *one by one*. Suffice to say, it's a doomed task. There are hundreds of others.

The point is **not** these are all rude/abusive. The problem is that these messages could **more effectively** and **sensitively** be conveyed with a little empathy.

Comment: Thanks for those examples. For the purposes of an easily digestible MCVE, it'd be great if you could add some more context to those first quotes if you have (though they are damning enough in and of themselves) and quote some relevant parts from those links here (they are a good illustration for what you're saying, but require a click-through to another lengthy thread…).

Comment: @deceze, Hmm, unfortunately many of these don't exist any more. Because they were flagged, usually after they had generated dozens of upvotes. Quotes are difficult. For example, take the penultimate: the response is (pretty much): "You are wrong! For reasons (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)." But the answer is *not even a response* to the original question, so there is a problem.

Comment: While I do agree with some points of the blog post, I do agree also a lot with the counter points by the community. That said, this answer is spot on, sometimes I myself sin of behaving like this, and I do agree we need to change the sarcasm and dismissive comments with everyone (regardless if there is or there is not a minority discrimination problem).

Comment: @AnderBiguri. Thank you for your insight. Yes, and we are *all* at fault. I have to *actively resist* the urge to upvote a funny comment when I sense it could also be rude. For example, how is a Bangladeshi programmer meant to feel if he read the first comment? He *might* laugh, but he might also bemoan the stereotype that is propagated. Why can't the point be made more neutrally? Like "We can't handhold everyone through their first steps on SO."

Comment: I have never seen anything remotely resembling these examples in over ten years. Exactly where did you chderry-pick them from?

Comment: @EJP, Cherry-picking suggests some pleasant imagery :). Trust me, I pick here the *better ones* because I wish to demonstrate an apparently unclear line. My cherry-picking criteria are: ~10-50 upvotes [SO helpfully highlights these] and unhelpful sarcy / potentially offensive. Yes, I court contention.

Comment: @EJP While the minority specific comments are rarer, you must have seen sarcastic and dismissive comments to newbies everywhere. They appear in the vast majority of bad newbie post.

Comment: Thanks for being my voice. The examples you shared are mine.

Comment: @jpp I definitely agree the call center imagery was oof.... but a lot of users would still be offended by "handhold".... Where is the line? That's a tough question this community will need to ponder...

Comment: @jpp oh I agree there. But that doesn't truly answer my question as to what to do about users who still find this message to be insulting. I don't think there is a good answer there, honestly.... but maybe you've thought of one? cause I know I haven't been able to muster one.

Comment: @jpp might be, might not be. My worry is that now, we are helping the truly insulted/offended/targeted/abused (however you want to frame it). Once that group is helped, will the group of people that don't like down/close/handholding comments get to be the more vocal ones? And will we then listen to their complaints? Maybe I'm being a bit paranoid here, and maybe nothing will go beyond what's happening now... I dunno, but I definitely see the potential for this

Comment: @Patrice, You're right. But we have to start somewhere. Thinking about people being offended by the word "handhold" is a non-issue until we stop all gender / ethnic stereotyping.

Comment: @jpp oh for sure. Baby steps, one at a time, we'll get through this. I just think we should also all be very attentive to the changes we propose/make, as this definitely has the potential of going too far and then hurting, instead of helping, this site.

Comment: FWIW, I can't see the aggression or the sarcasm in the two answers you link (they seem neutral in tone to me), and am unsure how you'd reword them to deliver the same message in a non-aggressive, non-sarcy way. I'm also not *sure* what particular issue you're pointing to with the first two quotes - that they're derogatory to Bangladeshis/religious people? - and can't see a problem with the third (besides being unsure what it *means*, out of context). Forgive me, but if these are representative examples, all I've learned is that I have no chance of not being offensive under these standards.

Comment: @MarkAmery, I'm not sure if your comment is serious, or whether you are being disingenuous. "It's even "rather important" to know how to change the oil in your car", in my opinion, is irrefutably sarcy and unnecessary. I'd love to have some of our StackExchange English colleagues to go through these posts and determine if they detect any overtones [coming from a **disinterested perspective helps here**]. Otherwise this will go round and round.

Comment: @jpp I'm sorry, but I don't get it. The oil changing example is a deliberately-constructed clearly-off-topic example of something "rather important" for a person to know, and is there to illustrate that being "rather important" cannot possibly be a *sufficient* reason for keeping a question open. As far as I can see, it serves that purpose pretty straightforwardly. What's the issue? With the use of such clearly off-topic examples in the first place? Or is there some cultural significance to changing car oil that I'm missing? I really have no idea what this is about.

Comment: If [this Martijn Pieters answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365643/2069064) is considered aggressive, then I feel like I'm clubbing baby seals on the regular. Same for [Nicol's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366050/2069064) that you linked.

Comment: @Barry, I guess we'll never know what those users felt. Because they've gone, perhaps forever. That's not because they're terrible users, mind you. They were asking good questions, even though I disagreed with them.

Comment: @jpp Frankly, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366049/2069064) strikes me as quite a bit more hostile than the answers you're complaining about. It's also much more of a demand than a question. But YMMV.

Comment: @jpp: "*I guess we'll never know what those users felt. Because they've gone, perhaps forever.*" Why do you discount the very real possibility that the reason they're gone is not the reception they got, but the actual *content* of the answer. Do you think TensorFlow guy would still be here if I'd been nicer about telling him "we're not going to lower our question quality because TensorFlow wants to use SO as its documentation site"?

Comment: @jpp: Here's a [fresh example... unfortunately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367091/are-we-supposed-to-take-something-from-the-replacement-blog-post).

Comment: I'm sure someone brought this up already, offense is taken, not given. If the two users took offense from the answers, there is no way the answerers could've rephrased to mean the same but not offend them.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Of course I've seen sarcastic comments, and I've posted them. What I have not seen, as I stated clearly, is minority-group-directed comments of the kind posted here. One of the many major problems with the blog we are discussing here is that it conflates the two and in the process accuses the entire community of implicit bias.

Comment: @EJP agreed, that is the major problem with the the blog post. However the blog post talks about the community and highlights problems with being welcoming, in general, too. Let's not ignore that we do have a problem with this as a community, regarthless of the problematic blog post.

Comment: @jpp I'm amused that you're telling me to "try reading" in the context of suggesting that users on SO are too hostile. That's a pretty aggressive remark to make. More so than how I interpret any of the answers you're complaining about.

Comment: Mind you, you're moving the goalposts. You previously were complaining that MP's answer was aggressive. Now you're complaining that it's not an actual answer. Two very different things.

Comment: A big documentation source for aggressive, self-satisfied, and the-problem comments is becoming the replies to these things on meta.

Comment: Could be because I'm not a native English speaker, but I don't see the gender or race or religious issue regarding third example _"There are several ways to say "of course not!" It is not clear which way you prefer."_. I only see it to be informative but incomplete or insufficiently descriptive.

Comment: @jpp I have enjoyed your input on the conversation since the blog post was put up. I see examples like yours above where there is nothing *overtly* aggressive but the writer's frustration and derision is plain. There is an attitude I encounter working in technology more than anywhere else that "Correct, concise, and explicit is best" is also taken to mean "If you feel bad about what I said to you, that's your second error" and before you know the answerer feels unappreciated, the asker feels disrespected, and communication deteriorates immediately.

Comment: @MackM, Thank you, your comment is insightful. One thing I would say is many people turn into defensive mode (cf comments on my post). I'm not saying there is anything *explicitly wrong* with the responses I have included [but this *may* also be true]. What I am saying is there *may* be more sensitive ways of answering which doesn't alienate users. Sarcasm, for example, will **never** come across positively for a user who sees -5 on their question. Nor will hyperbole ("It's rather important to change oil in your car."). No amount of newbie education / post moderation can solve this

Comment: @jpp I completely agree.  We are exploring technological, systemic, and administrative solutions to what I feel boils down to "Computer people have a reputation for poor social skills," "Neediness is annoying," "Asking for help makes people feel vulnerable," and "Online interactions are especially difficult". I'm seeing **highly** upvoted comments that are racially and gender insensitive at best around this conversation and am still unsure if that actually relates to the inclusivity problem like the blog post argues, or is just a deeply disappointing coincidence.

Answer (score 30):

I'm a straight white male with about as much privilege as can be given, and I felt INCREDIBLY intimidated on SO when I first started. I felt that I was given no direction or guidance how to behave, what made a "good" question, etc, and I was simply supposed to "know" those things, or be ridiculed for not knowing them. I was so afraid of getting a comment like those I had seen over and over and (in my mind) creating something that would significantly lower the quality of SO that I never posted a question, and when I finally did, I spent several hours combing over other questions to make sure I hadn't missed anything. It came off as very elitist, and there was a wide array of understanding I needed before I was capable of posting a "good" question.

Of course, in the years I've spent on here, I now understand that's not true. A "good" question is simply one that lays out the issues clearly, explains what's been tried, and isn't a duplicate of something easily found (I think it's really silly that we all have to say things like "sorry if this is a dupe, I couldn't find anything about it" because of the harsh blowback when a dupe is posted). I like SO, it's been the most helpful place in my career, and I'm on it probably every day. I think if new users were given a walkthrough of the site, how it works, and what's expected, it would be MUCH more welcoming, and the comments (while still sometimes unnecessarily sarcastic) would be more warranted, since the requirements have been clearly laid out.

With that said, I don't experience much of any discrimination on a day-to-day basis, and perhaps if I did, I would be more likely to assume that any harsh reaction *would* be about my race/gender/etc and I wouldn't even bother to post. That's a social reform discussion, not for here, but I do think that both above situations are reasons for SO to be more welcoming to *all* new users.

Just 2 cents from a dude with 53 rep, take it for what it's worth.

Comment: My observations (as subjective as they are) is that if a question is accompanied by all sorts of apology boilerplate, it can get a worse reception. It's meta commentary anyway, and it doesn't belong in a post, given that it is only relevant to the small percentage of readers who sign in and vote. The long tail of readers doesn't need to see this, and it's just noise to them.

Comment: Right and I think you're making my point...I think (some) people feel the need to add all of that in case they've made some mistake about some rule that's tucked away in some blog post somewhere and have seen enough snarky comments to know there won't be much grace if they've missed it.

Comment: I've considered [this phenomenon in detail here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions). The paradox is that you're asserting new users add nervous disclaimers in order to placate the audience, in case they might be hostile, but it has the effect of winding them up, because they interpret it as begging and pleading.

Comment: So, I agree with you in the sense that we can't magic away people's nervousness when they ask questions, but I also assert that if beginners use obsequious language, that becomes tiring for helpers who don't like being elevated onto a pedestal for every visit. My link examines some ways in which we could combat that. I take the view that "readers just need to be more understanding" is essentially a policy to do nothing (which is fine if it's the best solution, but I suspect it is not).

Comment: (Incidentally, I think this particular theme is more about human psychology than unwritten Stack Overflow guidelines and customs - I have a feeling this will happen in any volunteer community).

Comment: I am not sure *"elitist"* is understood outside of a North American context.

Comment: SO is just a somewhat harsh place for all of us. It's hits those that are more easily intimidated harder though.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Overflow is an international platform.

The tech industry is full of people of different ethnicities.

A lot of the online tutorials are made by "people of color".

It makes no sense in this particular industry to see prejudice against people of color

The user's identity, race and sex can be easily hidden.

I don't think that this is the problem. Even though it might be interpreted as such.

Your real problem is this mentality.

[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? (Answer by Anthony Pegram)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/261593/1)
<sup>In its originally posted, non-FAQ form, which sat untouched for 6 years.</sup>

Comment: I'm forced to agree...I don't wanna, but I'm forced to...

Comment: Although I will say that the answer is largely tongue-in-cheek and mostly sarcastic.  The advice that is given there - search, debug, trial, experiment, and *then* when you've exhausted all of your options, ask us - is spot on, since that's kind of what we assume is happening anyway.

Comment: If you have to hide your identity, race, or sex to have a good experience, then there is a problem.

Comment: @Andrew If you assume every problem you encounter is due to not hiding said information, there also is a problem.

Comment: I know this is a somewhat older answer, but I don't get it. What is the problem about the linked answer?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Observing the post's [full revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/261593/revisions?page=2) makes it clear that it gained some "special" attention in 2019 and was a source of controversy for a while. But then again, what Makoto said above, although it is not impossible that a non negligible number of people still have issues with the answer even after its revision.

Comment: @E_net4isoutofcommentflags That people felt the need to reformulate the answer still doesn't say *what* is wrong with it. Is it the spelling? The hyperbole? The demand for research? Something else I'm missing by glancing huge edit history?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Heh, YMMV, but some people had issue with the part where asking a question was an act of "horrible shame", in "vast amounts". Add that to the fact that it attracted lots of comments over time until moderators had to stop them completely. Let's just say that some people had no issue with shamelessly calling this out.

Answer (score 7):

Examples extracted from https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52:

1. > [image: If the error says at line 49, it tells you exactly where the problem lies. If you post 7 lines of code here, we clearly can't tell you what the problem is in line 49.]
   >
   > This was just posted by a guy with 100K+ rep on a beginner
   >   StackOverflow question.
   >
   > EQ note: Even this kind of subtly condescending comment can be very
   >   discouraging. The words "exactly" and especially "clearly" are warning
   >   signs in this context.
2. > Another woman shared this message she received on Stack Overflow
   >   after asking for help on a FlexBox margins issue:
   >
   > > “if you don’t get this…you have no business making a portfolio as a
   > >     web developer”
3. > My first SO qn got so many downvotes so quickly but no one bothered
   >   to/seemed to be able to answer it. Also, at least tell me what I did
   >   wrong please instead of just giving a passive aggressive response??
   >   I’ve always thought that it was my problem until I saw this today. So
   >   angry

   > I once tried to help on an so question and posted a link to a blog
   >   by the author of the library in question and why I found it really
   >   helpful.
   >
   > Next time I logged in I noticed I had developed a really negative
   >   score and response.
   >
   > Deleted my account and haven't looked back. :(
4. > As another sign of its inhumanity, Stack Overflow 
   >   [discourages greetings and thanks.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)

   > just tried to write an answer on stack overflow, it's a horrible 
   >   experience, but what really surprised me is that they edited my 
   >   answer and removed the "compassionate parts"..

   > A user with a mere 4,000 reputation edited the tags on my first
   >   question and took the opportunity to remove me saying ‘thanks’…
   >   That may seem like a tiny thing to some people, but I found it
   >   immensely offputting that a stranger was bothered enough by two 
   >   words of common politeness to silently remove them from my post.”
5. > [image: I'm not sure how to spell it out in plainer English. …]
6. > [image: Joke involving a nude girl with comments.]
   >
   > This response was up for nearly 10 years before it was removed after I tweeted about it.

Comment: In that first example, the word "exactly" is applicable, IMO. The experienced user is teaching the new user how to fish, instead of just giving them a fish.

Comment: @S.L.Barth The point, I believe, is that it would have been just as effective to say "The error message says the error is on line 49. Please tell us which line it is in the code you have posted here".

Comment: I would definitely agree with 2 and 5 being problematic. 1 can be read either way and is *very* subtle at best IMO. But yes, something to look out for. 3 and 4 seem like run-ins with site rules. I can sympathize with 3, but have no idea what to do about it without sacrificing SO. 6 is… mmm, well… we stopped accepting this kind of content anyway a long time ago. I see it as hardly offensive unless you want to be offended. YMMV.

Comment: @deceze I have exactly the same perplexities about that blog post but...hmmm...are these examples about _minorities_?! (or I just misunderstood your question?)

Comment: @deceze On 3a, it would perhaps help if allowing for multiple downvotes without a single explanatory comment was seen as a (not entirely satisfactory) compromise, rather than as a sacred right.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Quite honestly: *no,* most of this doesn’t seem to be specifically *against* anyone in particular. But it does help to see how *”minorities”* (in the vaguest definition of the word) perceive what’s going on on SO and why that might turn them off. Especially the point about “no thanks” is… illuminating.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Some of the discussion elsewhere was dedicated to this point. In particular, cf. the answers by [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366683/2751851) and [Michael Kay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366837/2751851) in a related question.

Comment: @duplode I agree it could have been phrased more nicely. But, the phrasing used teaches the new user (1) how to read error messages and (2) how to ask a question. The first, especially, is a vital skill for a developer. Not sure if a nicer wording would have taught the same lessons in so few words.

Comment: Tnx @duplode, good links!

Comment: @deceze What it puts off, I believe, is people who have little self-confidence. Which may or may not be caused by belonging to a minority group. But the underlying issue, I think, is one of self-confidence.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I would agree with that. One does need something of a thick skin, or at least particular mentality, to participate on SO. It may not be a problem for you and me, but if it turns off a number of people *needlessly* and we *can* do something about it (e.g. some of the harsh comments), we certainly should. I have no idea how to address the experienced issues with downvotes and closures though.

Comment: @deceze At the risk of bringing up a pet issue of mine, maybe we could look at the H&I queue. Most reviews there are edits. They improve a new user's post but don't teach anything about how the site works. Maybe that review queue should focus more on Helping new users navigate the myriad rules of our site... rather than Improving their posts.

Comment: I don't understand how any of the examples here are related to minorities? Were they supposed to be?

Comment: Examples 2 and 5 are valid concerns; I think 1, 3, and 4 are invalid. 6 looks like it's from that old joke thread which should be entirely nuked from orbit anyway. But, it also is clear from that thoughtfluencing post that the author has a bone to pick and doesn't consider balance at all. She doesn't account for the fact that there are literally millions of posts on this site and only, what, a couple dozen people who look for stuff beyond newly posted content?

Comment: @mason See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366867/mcve-for-not-being-very-welcoming?noredirect=1#comment581097_366890. That may be one of the most misunderstood things about this whole episode… the issue (as I see it so far) isn't really about specific acts of misogyny, racism or such, it's about how ["minorities"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366867/mcve-for-not-being-very-welcoming?noredirect=1#comment580830_366867) experience some of the things "we" take as par for the course.

Comment: Can we define, with some data, for example from 2018 survey (https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile) which are the minorities?! It seems SO population is pretty diverse. We are talking about _minorities_ when the problem might be just about a bunch of _sensible_ guys which expect sugar words while trying to save their own time and _wasting_ time of someone else...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I wouldn’t word it that harshly. I still have yet to see evidence of specific misogynistic or racist behavior or anything of that sort. However, if some of the things in these examples cause certain minorities to withdraw from SO sooner than others — and I don’t know to what extend it’s a *minority* issue or an issue with individuals of any group — and we agree that it stems from behavior we discourage anyway, then we should certainly be sensitive to that.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti according to your link, women are a minority (10%). So suppose we defined that. Then what?

Comment: #1 has *got* to be me.

Comment: @Will Mind if I post-hoc suspend you for a week? ;)

Comment: Why? Because I used the words "exactly" and "clearly"? Oh, crap, I just used them! I'm bound for SO jail!

Comment: @deceze wording was harsh on purpose. Any reason a minority reading that should feel hmmm discriminated? I honestly think that if SO is sometimes "rude" there isn't absolutely any discrimination in that. We're equally rude to everyone regardless race, sex, gender, age, culture and religion. If someone wants to feel discriminated (someone mentioned a problem with self-esteem) then, well, it's THEIR problem (and a therapist may help). Treat internet strangers as colleagues, right? Will you use kid gloves with a colleague because she belongs to a minority? That's discrimination.

Comment: @evk good, now if someone wants to talk about sex at birth discrimination then they should compare number of downvotes according to that and maybe seniority otherwise it's just "bla bla" without any evidence

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I agree that “discrimination” seems to be the wrong framing for this. However, as a hypothetical case, say, a young girl who, for whatever reason, is already fighting an uphill battle with joining the computer science field, may indeed finally be throwing in the towel when confronted with comments such as #2. I can see that being a possibility. Some MVCE for that would be nice, but we can work from this assumption. There’s probably a middle ground before *needs-therapy* that we *can* take care of with little effort.

Comment: Imo, most of these are a little... “meh”. I’m used to blunt, to the point communication. One can immediately decide they don’t like the way something’s written, or have another look at _what is said_ instead of how it’s said. Only #2 is problematic, but easily handled by flagging it.

Comment: I dunno how intrinsically problematic even #2 is. If someone on the home improvement site asked "how deep should the teeth of my bandsaw bite into my hand for a good grip", responses along the lines of *you have no business using power tools stop that immediately* would be entirely warranted. Depending on how bad the question in #2 was (we don't know), it's entirely possible that the person had no business doing web development and was likely to cause data loss or other serious damage.

Comment: (A bunch of asynchronous replies follow) @TylerH #3 looks invalid if we think of it merely as an attempt to enforce the site rules. However, we might want to consider how easy it can be for a new user -- even for one who would be willing to cooperate, and who might be just one misunderstanding away from a good first post -- to have a run-in with one of our many rules. [Travis J's newly-posted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366956/2751851) frames that issue well IMO.

Comment: @Cerbrus #5 may be blunt, but it is not to the point. Those four initial sentences add nothing of value to the answer.

Comment: @user2357112 Even so, I don't think it is up to us to tell other users what they are allowed to do. (Or to be: "you have no business making a portfolio as a web developer" is this close to "give up, choose another career". By the way, taking that into account, I'd say the power tools example you give is significantly milder than #2). Even if it *really* comes down to having to tell someone they have to learn to walk before they can run (I sometimes do that when faced with implausibly broad homework questions), it can be done in a way that is actionable and not judgemental.

Comment: @Cerbrus: "*Only #2 is problematic, but easily handled by flagging it.*" That all depends on how you define "handled". From the perspective of the site, yes, it will be handled: the comment will be removed. But from the perspective of the person to whom the comment was directed, *the damage has been done*. The poster of that comment got to attack the person who posted the question. Arresting a mugger is a good thing, but that doesn't change the fact that someone got mugged. The police can't fix that; you need a societal solution.

Comment: @NicolBolas: it’s impossible to _prevent_ harassment from happening. All we can do is deal with it quickly and harshly. If a new user doesn’t understand this, frankly, they need to read the manual on “the internet” once again. The best we can hope for, is a new user seeing: _”well that guy was a douche, but at least ge got banned quickly!”_

Comment: @Cerbrus Only, nobody usually sees that second part. At best comments are deleted and that’s that. There’s no “positive follow up.” Perhaps that is something to change.

Comment: @deceze One of the core issues is that discrimination goes both ways. Why would/should young girl be any different than young boy fighting same uphill battle? Equal treatment is imperative, regardless of whether you treat them nicely or not.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar as you can see from comments I'd tend to agree with you but I suppose Deceze is trying to say that we should be "nice" with everyone. Obviously I don't agree with that, I mean: it's mandatory to be kind but SO isn't here to be help people to face their own problems (especially because "real life" outside SO isn't like that).

Comment: Every single one of those "examples" kind of prove the **opposite** of *unwelcoming*, they prove that **how you feel about someone else's actions/behavior is completely your own problem**, every therapist and psycologist will tell you that you are the master of your own **feelings**. If you internalize a down vote or an objective comment that tells you it is impossible to tell what line 49 is out of 7 lines of code, as a personal attack on yourself, that is your problem. and it is a problem that no one here is responsible for.

Comment: *Deceze is trying to say that we should be "nice" with everyone*, what you have to understand is there is a point that **not everyone will allow you to be nice to them or accept it if they are looking to be offended first**

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I completely agree. Even more: not everyone deserves kindness. If they're happy to waste our time because they don't turn on brain even when asking for help...then a slightly harsh response is the best they should get. However I admit that example #2 is extreme, ad personam attacks are rarely constructive (and of course they'll be perceived as personal)

Comment: @feeling Yes, I do think we treat everyone the same. However, especially #2 and #5 really show that we are also equally rude sometimes, and while this might not faze you or me, it *does* faze some people more. And since we *don't* know who we're dealing with, we might inadvertently be hitting people in the face without realising it. If you *did* see that you're dealing with a fragile person you might choose a different tone, which can make all the difference.

Comment: *“if you don’t get this…you have no business making a portfolio as a web developer”* how is this misogynist or any more offensive because it was on a question by a female? We do not even see if her name or avatar gave away that she is female? It could just be an asshole comment, but because it was received by a woman it is worse? What if the commenter were female? We do not see any implication of the gender of the commenter. But the implication is that is it is misogynist behavior. I seen nothing in this any better or worse if it was directed at a man ( by another man or woman )

Comment: @deceze I agree that #2 is an example of bad behaviour because it's directed to the OP, it's a personal statement, it's highly opinion based and utterly harsh but it has nothing to do with race or gender or whatever.

Comment: Honestly I **REALLY** care about discrimination. When I first woke up and I saw that in the real world there is discrimination...I was...shocked. Is it even possible? That's idiotic! That's why I find incredibly offensive to talk about discrimination when someone is just too sensible and they're using discrimination as a shield for their own faults. Do you remember the fable of the wolf and the lamb?

Comment: All these said...well...if we don't try to keep quality slightly higher than now then we'll have a site full of junk. Also full of kind comments but without anyone to answer anything you can't find with a Google search. I think it's not a case that Documentation had such big number of contributions but MANY old/high-rep SO users are answering less and less (if not leaving).

Comment: @Adriano I agree that framing the discussion as "discrimination" of any sort is bad and counter productive. I'm also not sure in how far this was ever spelled out, implied, or merely read-into. The bottom line pretty much seems to be that things we perceive as rude anyway does cause a number of people (how sizeable we don't know) to turn away entirely, which really should be avoidable. Other things may be a mismatch of expectations and reality, which [may be solvable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366956/476). But yes, it'll be impossible to not offend anyone ever either.

Comment: So are we now encouraging greetings and thanks?

Comment: @immibis No. I can see though how something like that piles onto the negative impression everything else already provides. But that falls into the *mismatch-between-expectations-and-reality* clause IMO. SO is really more like Wikipedia than anything else, but is [perceived as a forum or Reddit.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366956/content-rules-and-perceptions#comment581976_366956)

Comment: I agree with that, for sure something can be done to please both _old_ and _new_ users (possibly and probably also to keep high traffic to also please who from SO has to get money, of course). As usual a nice compromise ("punish" needless offensive behaviours but leave insecure sensible guys to fly away, if they wish so). I just "flame" because that blog post is using a sensible topic (discrimination) to justify low quality questions (because, well...traffic is money). Or maybe it's not because of that but because to be politically correct is mandatory nowadays then it's nice to include it.

Comment: @Adriano I don't think The Blog Post™ really insinuated any particular causes or specific actions. It was vague enough so everyone reads different things into it, which is part of the issue of framing this discussion. (Correct me if I'm wrong, I can't be bothered to re-read that thing again at the moment. :))

Comment: @deceze you're right, it was pretty vague (I'd say _insinuating_ but I'm biased). They wrote that (in)famous sentence but then suggested solutions were for low quality posts leaving the reader to do the homework and find a correlation between them (if any). Annoying but maybe we're just shaking mountains for a very unfortunate wording (or an innocent and failed attempt to be p.c.)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Of course, main goal is to be nicer to everyone. My main point is, that positive discrimination can be as bad as negative discrimination. Women, or members of any minority group don't need special treatment.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I **completely** agree with that.

Comment: @Dalija Yes, "positive discrimination" means it's okay to be rude to white men, but not to others. That's discrimination right there in the definition. I'd say that unless you know who you're dealing with personally ("my buddy Jake"), you should assume you're helping an insecure teenager and be nice appropriately.

Comment: I'm not a psychologist but maybe an insecure teenager should start to face the reality right now. It's easier to face strong criticisms on Internet than in person then we're just teaching them to be ready for the world. Hmmmm Why the f...they don't say "thank you"?! LOL

Comment: Do no one has problems with not being able to have context? I mean, the only one we can have context is an answer of '12. It seems like cherry-picking. And the other was a response to a joke question... I've always had problem with that joke question, not because the jokes are bad, but that they don't belong here. I feel that most of the examples would happen only if there was something rule-breaking before it.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I dislike the isolated examples too. However, I think most of these *can* stand on their own. The point is, we don't want to see (some of) that kind of content on the site, no matter what the rationalisation is. (We don't, right?)

Comment: Well, how about starting by deleting the joke question? I mean, we don't want to have this kind of content, right? Lets not keep the things that motivates the kind of content to be posted in the first place.

Comment: @duplode On #3, yes I agree that our closure notices/system need some work, but it is invalid because 1) the author of the Medium post is quoting someone else there 2) it's not passive-aggressive 3) it's a case where the user is being unreasonable IMO; we don't know if that user left a comment asking what was going on or just silently suffered? It's lacking context.

Comment: @Braiam I agree, we should delete that joke question.

Comment: @TylerH about #3 unfortunately he didn't post that ranting on SO.meta otherwise we were able to answer "bye bye" (and then discuss if that's appropriate or not...)

Comment: 4. I just flagged a comment yesterday for saying "Thanks for helping fix my English." or something for being unnecessarily chatty  and it immediately disappeared! Since I don't have moderator privileges, others must have flagged it too. This comment will probably be flagged as well for being chatty.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I think we can all be grateful your not a therapist. People have issues, a lot of people are dealing with rather serious issues, issues that will only be exacerbated by a glib "grow a thicker skin" comment. I fail to see why being more vulnerable is a sufficient reason for being exclude from a society like StackOverflow.

Comment: I spent some time thinking about each of the examples provided.  For every one I see no problem with the "offensive" comment.  Example 6 at first glance is most questionable but explain who should be offended there?  Seems to be most directed at the social inadequacies of CS students.  Yet some will say it demeans the woman, and I won't argue that point.  As in all cases, offense can be taken by anyone over anything.

Comment: @AkselA I was under the impression that the half joking tone of that comment was obvious. In reality I do not mean "grow a thicker skin" but "live with it or go away". It's not the role and purpose of SO to nurse someone with self-esteem/self-acceptance problems or utterly sensible personalities seeking acceptance in a community which has to change its own de-facto rules to make space for them.Offensive? Never. Kid gloves for someone who does not bother to read at least our FAQ before seeking for help? For help vampires? Never.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366816/1207195 explains what I mean much better than myelf

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I fail to see the joke, all I see is arrogance. Why shouldn't SO be interested in amassing a diverse as possible user base? We deal with a wealth of problems, a wealth of possible perspectives would be a great asset. Yet, by not discouraging excessively crass conduct, these perspectives are lost.

Comment: @AkselA because, it doesn't matter how hard you try, you can't make it a fit for everyone. Of course unless you want to see SO as a place where literally everyone can dump some junk asking for help instead of turning their own brain on at least for 10 seconds. That's the whole point: **to teach people to ask a decent question is the BEST thing you we can do. It's even more important than an answer for an immediate problem.** Who doesn't want to learn that can (IMO) stay away.

Comment: Think it this way: we have a finite (and limited) amount of time we can dedicate to SO. I used to answer some questions every day. Now I maybe answer one question per month. It doesn't mean I do not come to SO...just that the small amount of time I can dedicate to it is lost browsing garbage, downvoting and/or closing. Sometimes I just go away because it's boring. To accept junk is not a benefit for SO (I'm not talking about money generated by traffic...) because good decent answers will go unnoticed and unanswered. Should we be nice to people wasting _our_ time and killing the good of SO?

Comment: @Adriano If I may interject: I think it's not that black and white. There's a spectrum of quality. Utter garbage is utter garbage, good questions are good questions, and then there's the grey zone in the middle which could go either way, which is probably where a lot of *naïve newbies* fall (give that term a charitable interpretation). I think the issue The Blog Post is about to a large degree is that this middle zone could be treated a lot better and brushed up with little effort, but is often lumped in with the utter garbage instead. Caring for the middle doesn't require caring for garbage.

Comment: In my opinion answer is NO. It doesn't mean we have to be rude (comments like "stupid donkey, go to read the f* manual first" have never been tolerated) but also it doesn't mean that we must use kid gloves (also and especially because to deal with this junk is time consuming). Is it elitist? No, probably **many SO users are just proud of what they're doing here: HELP. For free.** With only (maybe) some gratitude as reward. Should we nurse new users with polite and delicate comments 100 times a day because they don't have time to read "how to ask" section?! Seriously?

Comment: @deceze I agree but the problem are the numbers. Get rid of the extremes and people will be much nicer with the gray. You may say "ignore them or do not answer at all". I'm doing that but it's OK only if it's my own problem, if everyone willing to answer just navigates away then you may have 1^9 sub-optimal questions nursed with great effort to become _decent_ but no one to answer them.

Comment: @Adriano Yes, numbers are a problem. I think specifically because there is a lot of garbage, many have developed a trigger finger and cynicism which steamrolls over that middle zone, when they could and probably would have otherwise helped more nicely. My working hypothesis is that that's where a lot of the grumbling comes from (in my examples here #2, #3 and maybe #5).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti:  "stupid donkey, go to read the f* manual first" would not be accepted, but RTFM or variants thereof are quite common. People making such comments might have forgotten quite how impenetrable the manuals can be to a newcomer. I don't believe I'm asking for the moon here, or that we should lower our standards, but there are nice ways, and not so nice ways, in which you can ask a newbie to do some research/debugging on their own.

Comment: @deceze I agree with that, what I think is that the "problem to solve" isn't the cynicism (which is a symptom) but the endless stream of garbage (which is the cause). For #2 and #3 I completely and absolutely agree. Especially for #2 there should not be space on SO. #3...well...a link only answer is doomed to be downvoted...nothing to complain about (IMO).

Comment: @AkselA I don't say we shouldn't try to be more helpful and kind with beginners, that's what SO is for. I'm saying that the beginner should be willing to learn and to accept "house rules": answer comments ASAP, fix his question, accept downvotes without crying, read at least the "how to ask" section before asking (or face their destiny otherwise). That said...someone even complained for LMGTFY...hey...if they didn't...they should at least accept some sarcasm (IMO)...

Comment: Anyway, I already deal with this problem almost stopping to actively participate to SO, that's not the point. What made me FURIOUS was the ridiculous accusation to SO community (then also to me) to be racist, sexiest and bla bla bla.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti who's saying it's racist and sexist?

Comment: @immibis The Blog Post, that's the source of all these discussions. He seems to suggest/imply/insinuate that questions aren't evaluated according to their technical merit but about color, race and sex of the OP.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The blog post is not making such an accusation or insinuation. This point was addressed in a few places amidts these discussions; [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366963/2751851) puts it clearly, while [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366966/2751851) also covers it to an extent.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti [Yakk's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367053/2751851) is also relevant.

Comment: @duplode that's why we're here discussing about it...because wording is (as I said in another comment before) absolutely unfortunate. Saying that a "woman experiences SO as hostile" does not directly say that we're sexist but it insinuates it. Is it hostile because women post worse questions? Because women cannot write a full sentence in English? Why?! What does it imply? Talking about "shift focus" is just trying (IMO) to serve an half-baked cake: yes there is this problem, you're not responsible, they're not responsible...then?

Comment: I understand that "they" just expressed a feedback they received. I do not doubt that. However they had to do their homework BEFORE the post. Which are the percentages? What's the evidence? It doesn't matter what...that blog post will be used to label SO community as racist and sexist. If there is a problem (they say), if the problem isn't with the group ("people of color", women, blueberry cheesecake eaters) (unless the lesson that we have to learn is that people subject to discrimination are also more prone to complaining...I doubt that's enough to trigger that post)...

Comment: ...then the problem is with the community, and I want to know it

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The "What does it imply?" question is, I believe, addressed by the staff replies I link to in my answer mentioned above. By the way, I feel that seeing in the blog post an insinuation that, for instance, "women cannot write a full sentence in English" just because it suggests that women might have a poorer experience here than the norm is, in a way, jumping to a conclusion -- it perhaps suggests overconfidence in that we can do no wrong in how we enforce and present our rules.

Comment: @duplode Tim's posts don't address racism (as far as I can tell). "Sorry but that's it"? Where the evidence is? "Trust us" is not an acceptable answer if you put it down black on white on a public forum. Shog's posts are unrelated (to racism) but interesting for the other part of the discussion (quality): in the first one he links to another Tim's post which...says..."sorry but it's the price to pay for quality" Hmmmmmm and in the second one that downvoted users come back as much as upvoted ones.

Comment: @deceze: That same article also gave https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4175878/revisions as a good example of offensive anti-transgendered ramblings in a question (about storing a gender field in a database) being left up for 8 years. (e.g. *I guess the most appropriate name for a boolean (gender) column would be `hasPenis`*)  An edit in 2013 fixed it, then the OP rolled it back to their offensive version right away.  Having that content stay up for that many years with all but one person who saw it ignoring the problem is not a good sign for the community in those tags.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti They don't address racism precisely because the post isn't essentially about discriminatory behaviour. [Tim's first answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366683/2751851) covers that. Quoting its first paragraph: "There's an intersection at which we're very certain that groups of people who experience discrimination or other effects of marginalization in life *do not engage* with Stack Overflow because our perceived lack of empathy is often exacerbated by their own (typically awful) personal experiences."

Comment: @duplode tnx now I see your point and I agree but, if this is the concept they were supposed to communicate, I find the wording extremely poor and unclear. I'm not a native English speaker then it might well be my fault but - given the outcomes of that post - I'd seriously hope they'll edit it to be much more explicit.

Comment: It's sad that #1 is considered aggressive. Beyond that, salutations and pre-emptive gratitude have been stripped out, dispassionately, for years. It's not supposed to be about the OP; it's supposed to be about making that Q&A set useful for future visitors.

Comment: I don't know why the joke was offensive.

Comment: @Benjol, agreed, that's a good joke.

Answer (score 7):

> - Anything else I'm not thinking of?

They asked potential users (software developers) how they interact with Stack Overflow.

Such questions might look like:

Do they post questions? If so, how was the experience? If not, why not?

You also ask about various demographic information (age, salary, location, language, culture/race, etc.).

When you get interesting data (like "lots of people find Stack Overflow unwelcoming"), you can go and get *more* data about that piece.

But along the way, you may notice that (A) many people think it is unwelcoming, and (B) some groups find it more unwelcoming than others.

You can then drill down and find out why it is unwelcoming. But you don't have to be spewing racist slurs for something to be felt more unwelcoming to a minority group than to the majority group.

In Stack Overflow's case, there are *lots* of low hanging fruit that makes the experience less welcoming. Before you narrow-cast at the problem from a specific subgroup experience, find the low hanging fruit and pluck it. Then iterate.

It isn't hard to see that someone might find asking a question on Stack Overflow is unwelcoming. It disproportionately landing on already marginalized groups within the developer community is *not surprising*. Observing that this is happening isn't evidence of mass racism or sexism (beyond the background racism/sexism). Regardless of that, it is still evidence of a *problem*.

It appears their first run at it will be to find unwelcoming parts of the experience and shore them up. The structured help in asking a question may reduce the rude awakening when someone types a "poor" question and hits "ask".

---

**NOTHING** in the post you are referring to implies or claims any bias on the part of any member of Stack Overflow. It states that people from group X feel less welcome, and that many people feel unwelcome.

This fact does not depend on members of Stack Overflow trying to make them feel less welcome, being biased, or even any difference in treatment whatsoever.  It is an observation.

It manifests in the people who feel unwelcome. It does not require specific targetted behavior on the part of Stack Overflow posters for it to manifest. There may also be such targetted behavior (which you are asking for), but nothing in the plan to reduce this problem nor in the blog post requires such targetted behavior to exist nor be provided.

Only after remedy of the unwelcoming behavior is attempted and appears to work *but not on the minorities in question* would you then go off and try to find what unwelcoming behavior that is specifically unwelcoming to minorities, beyond a general "blatant racism and sexism is a reason to delete something" pass.

Comment: Two quotes in particular: " we are (unintentionally) biased ourselves."  and "If you’re shaking your head thinking, “not me,” I’d encourage you to take these implicit bias tests".  That being said, as I commented on another post, the actual remedies match your idea of "low-hanging fruit". The "bias" thing was just bolted on for extra PC.

Comment: "NOTHING in the post you are referring to implies or claims any bias on the part of any member of Stack Overflow. It states that people from group X feel less welcome" +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the questions that made me ask this question today:

- *[What does MCVE mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean)*

*At the time of writing this*, I've received ***five*** downvotes.

It's cases like this that make me think I shouldn't contribute to this site anymore. At what point does a question become worthy of being on the site?

If I asked multiple questions that get downvoted a lot, instead of telling me how to improve and giving me guidance, I'd be blocked from asking questions. New people have a distinct disadvantage right from the start.

Comment: Could you please clarify why this feels unfair to you as a *member of a minory group*? From the outside it looks like you are being downvoted for asking what is perceived as a trivial question.

Comment: Unless you got a warning from the system, I don't think you're at risk of being question-banned on MSO. Overall your contributions here seem to have been received well. And MSO is more forgiving than the main site, because here votes are also used to express disagreement.

Comment: I'm not talking about minority groups here, I'm saying as a general 'new-ish' user to the site. It may seem trivial to some, but in most cases in life, if you don;'t ask, you don't get. So I asked and seem to have been told that was wrong by the way of downvotes.

Comment: Just pick any minority group you belong to, everyone belongs to a bunch of minority groups. *Bearded polo-shirt wearer with lisp and mole doing part time  modelling.* 

Comment: @deceze so... you are my greatest enemy then, as I am part of *Bearded polo-shirt wearer with lisp and **without** mole doing part time modeling*

Comment: @Patrice Oh I hate that mole-less rubble…!

Comment: @deceze Lisp? C'me on, true beards use C, not Lisp! :-D

Comment: @DanielJames if someone has some more time you may get http://lmgtfy.com/?iie=1&q=MCVE (which, at least for me, gave me https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as the very first entry). Now, it's true that often an arid comment is enough (and you will quickly delete the question by yourself) but after all votes are the foundation of SO then...

Comment: @DanielJames: "*At what point does a question become worthy of being on the site?*" Well, here's one suggestion. If you type the question title into Google, if the answer is in the top 10 results, it's probably not worthy of the site.

Comment: @NicolBolas The [top rated question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5255018), has 21k votes, and a lot of assorted google answers. is that question not worthy of this site? - you could say the same about the rest of the top rated questions here. Are all of those unworthy? Maybe the professional/ kind/helpful way to answer this question is to mark it as duplicate and point to a properly answered question

Comment: and if it isn't a duplicate, then it absolutely deserves an answer. Else we should just tell @DanielJames that he simply isn't worthy of being here. To go and play on Quora instead.

Comment: @MichaelB Er, all the first page results on Google for "Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?
" are _newer_ than the question itself, and at least half _refers to it_. So, not a great example.

Comment: @MichaelB __There is a canonical answer on the site already__ and it is a google search away. Say every user that have the same problem with branch prediction asks a question and waits to be redirected. You now have a million more questions to close as dupe. Are you seriously suggesting this is the right way to go?

Comment: @PasserBy I've not actually got the numbers behind the number of dupe closes, but I doubt there's a million. If occasionally a new user sees that, doesn't understand what it means and decides to ask. Why do we need to be so rude - why not post a link to the canonical answer (nobody has) - why not dupe that question to the canonical answer? (nobody has tried) - Why is a moderator answering that question if a canonical already exists? - If it is such a bad question, why hasn't it been closed?

Comment: Actually, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280) makes my point considerably more eloquently than I ever could - or did.

Comment: I'm sorry that your question here, and the other question linked, were downvoted. Be comforted by the fact that downvotes on the meta site don't count against your rep score.

Answer (score -15):

The problem sometimes, is that SO can also be quite anti-intellectual. I wanted to post a self-answer Q&A because, after struggling for a while, I finally worked out a solution to my problem. So I wrote up my question with an answer that I felt would help others only for it to get downvoted and voted to close because it was a "link based" question. Seeing as how SO didn't want the Q&A, I have decided to keep all self-documentation to, well... myself from now on.

[Special status for questions with self-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297834/special-status-for-questions-with-self-answers)

Comment: We require that code that's important for answering the question be put into the question, not hidden behind a link.

Comment: @NicolBolas Now here's the problem. 1. this pertains to a plugin, if the plugin dies, goes away or whatever, the question because irrelevant anyway. 2. This is a self-answered Q&A. I posted it because I thought that other people who might be struggling may find it helpful. In no way does anyone else need to contribute. I wouldn't mind comments asking me to add clarity, but just downvoting without any comments is the reason why people think this site is nasty. 3. This is a net loss for SO. I will ALWAYS have a copy of this documentation. Now SO does not. But do keep driving people away.

Comment: "*This is a self-answered Q&A.*" Being self-answered does not and *should not* exempt people from the rules. It's good that you wanted to provide a useful artifact for others, but on SO, that always starts with a *good question*. "*In no way does anyone else need to contribute.*" Stack Overflow is not a blog service. Self-answered Q&As are not a way for you to use our site to say whatever you want. They're a way for you to provide useful information within our rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas If it was a bad question and people wanted it be clarified, that's fine. Except I had no input. And I even gave a link where Jeff Attwood states this is encouraged https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ But w/e, maybe something else will come along in the future that's more self-documentation friendly.

Comment: Why do you keep repeating that it was a self-answered question as though that absolves you from something? If your question had been asked and not been self-answered, it would have been closed. That's the rule with self-answered questions; they have to be just like *regular* questions. You had input; you had your question. You could have made it a good question, and the close reason and comments told you exactly what you needed to do.

Comment: The question didn’t provide enough content *in itself* to even understand what it is about. It has virtually no useful content/keyword/explanation. That makes it hard for future readers to find/understand/apply. It’s great that you want to self-document things, but then you need to do that with enough context so it’s actually useful. *That* was the entire issue with it.

Comment: Your question wasn't well structured - it's very broad, contains a link that may expire, and doesn't really explain the problem at all. But the content in your answer is potentially very useful. And you're right, getting downvoted without explanations (that you find meaningful) is crappy. Ideally someone helps you craft a better question. But in general users take the approach that if you don't write a good question then you don't deserve help.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst and that's kind of the problem. I wasn't asking for help, I was GIVING knowledge. If the question needed to be expanded on, like giving more code from the actual server file or w/e I would probably have expanded on it. Hell, if someone wanted to edit the question, I would have probably accepted it.

Comment: One way to avoid the downvotes is to prepare comments in advance (explaining why it is a self-answer -  shouldn't really be necessary, but it is) and submitting them seconds after posting the question and answer.

Answer (score -26):

I asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186463/invalid-syntax-using-percentage-sign) today in which [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) called my code nonsense.

I admit that I have a lack of knowledge on how things work with respect to some of the syntax, as I program mainly using visual programming and only come to Stack Overflow in the rare times when I am directly using Python or C#. The tags I used (grasshopper, rhino and python) should give context that I probably don't know much about text programming.

So why does this place not only feel hostile to people of the "fairer" gender and/or POC, of which I am both, but also feel unwelcoming as a whole to people who don't deal with text-based programming on a daily basis?

I find it baffling because, within my friends and professional colleagues, the ability to use Grasshopper with minimal text-based programming is lauded. Yet because our experience with text-based programming is minimal, our questions are met with derision, and the duplicity of the reactions stumps me and leaves me at a loss of what to do. This is because I don't understand how to reach my goals, and I can't hope to understand what I'm doing wrong when such harsh language is used in response to my questions.

In short, it is entirely unfriendly to those who use Stack Overflow as a landing page for text-based programming when their main approach is visual programming.

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea what you are trying to say. Can you please rewrite it a little clearly?

Comment: You must be referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58186463/1079354).  I'm not sure where you got hostility from in that context; when looking at that code as a Python professional, I can't really make sense of it either.  Yes, there *are* syntax errors there.  No, the fact that you use visual programming languages is not a relevant factor in your specific question.  No, it's *not* clear what any of that is meant to actually *be*.  I get that you're not an expert at Python - no one expects that - but you should be prepared to answer questions of the code you wrote.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "gh visual programming" and "text based programming"?

Comment: If your broad point was that someone was rude or unfriendly on the main site, then you can flag for a moderator to draw attention to either of these things. Use the "flag" device against a question, answer, or comment.

Comment: gh = grasshopper. we do a sort of programming by linking components. tldr its like actual text based programming coding cuz theres the logic in between components and all, but the thing is that was my exact issue with it all: I had a logic going on, I thought my code would work, but it didn't and I felt like calling what I thought was said logic etc nonsense just because I didnt know the nuances of a variable variable nonsense was pure hostility.

Comment: Althea, as you're new to the site, a couple of tips for using it effectively:1) when replying to someone in comments, in order to notify them you need to put a`@` in front of their screen name; 2) Stack Overflow is *not* a "forum", so there are no automatic notifications; 3) Discussions must be on-topic, please consult the guidelines on Stack Overflow *MAIN* site about how to ask questions in the HELP. 4) You should NOT ask questions in an *ANSWER*. This is a Q&A venue: One question and one or more answers. If you wnat to ask something, start a new question.

Comment: @CindyMeister its a rhetorical question...

Comment: @AltheaC I've tried to rephrase your post a little to make it a bit clearer and to focus more on the points I thought you were making. If that's not OK, you can always revert the changes. I'm truly sorry your experience with Stack Overflow has been so negative.

Comment: "Making sense" is a feature of an idea, concept or meaning that can be reasoned upon, logically defended or else soundly talked about. That something does not make sense is neither an attack nor a slight, it is an evaluation of a concept. Every programmer will produce things that do not make sense. If you start thinking that someone pointing it up are being mean, you will make everyone sad everywhere you will work. Being able to tell things as they are, either nonsensical ou full of sense, is essential if you want to get anything done.

Comment: A typical reaction is to [ditch Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-zEUl2UmJo&t=4m52s). Part of it is the failure of the base software to set the right expectations.

Comment: Thanks @Welbog. I also realized from answers to my question is that the rhino environment doesn't provide much info to the error or how to correct it etc. They just tell you where the error is, and I wonder if SO can have a page to teach people how to do a bit more advanced programming. Back when I received the first few answers, I had never heard of variable variables even, or known it was a thing. If I had known, I would have made my question a bit more specific than just saying "help, i have syntax error and dont know why"

Answer (score -66):

The question contains a great example: *"And remember that the plural of anecdote is not data"*

Dismissing people's experiences because they are not "data" is a great way to make them feel unwelcome. You are saying to them that you consider their experience invalid because they have failed to meet your arbitrary standard of proof that it is a real issue.

Another excellent example of this is Dalija Prasnikar's comment: *"Problem with people belonging to "minority" groups is that the second something bad happens they will instantly jump to the conclusion it is because they belong to some minority group."* This is another case of preemptively invalidating complaints due to the complainer's minority status.

In fact, we can see a pattern of this on meta right now. The amount of push-back against this blog post, mostly on the basis of denying that there is a problem or claiming that [acknowledging the problem victimizes some other group](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonising-the-quality-concerned-users-who) creates a very hostile environment for those affected.

Comment: "arbitrary standard" haha

Comment: _"This is another case of preemptively invalidating complaints due to the complainer's minority status."_ You're way off-target there. The point of those statements is that their being part of _"minority <x>"_ is ___irrelevant___. SO isn't "hostile" to new users because of their (lack of) gender, race, species, sexual preference or whatever. SO is perceived as hostile to new users, by users asking ___bad___ questions. Whether or not that user belongs to a minority doesn't matter, and shouldn't be __used__ as a means to make us feel bad about downvoting bad content.

Comment: I totally read something else in that sentence, as in *don't just query a database, give example(s) that are in context* but I guess YMMV. All our words seem futile here and all we achieve is more pain. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Cerbrus You are dismissing people who tell you it is an issue in their experience of using the site. I can show you examples of it not being relevant, but then those will be written off as anecdotes. I don't think you did that intentionally, but it's an argument designed by less honourable people to silence such concerns, which has unfortunately been rebranded as "rationalism" to make it more mainstream.

Comment: This answer commits an extremely common error in conflating two different things. First, it claims that an insistence on (statistical) data is used to invalidate anecdotal evidence (and therefore that *individual outliers* are handled improperly), then jumps to the conclusion that this must be handled by *broad, systemic, generalized* changes. Making systemic changes entirely on the basis of outliers that are not representative of the wider state *is exactly the kind of real error statistics was rigorously formalized to prevent*. What we *can* do is fix up individual cases — separately.

Comment: No, I'm saying that the _"SO is unwelcoming"_ issue isn't a race / gender / sexuality / whatever issue. It's an issue of how (harshly) we deal with low quality content, and ___how that is perceived___ by the user who's being told "no". We can improve that, but that has nothing to do with the user's physical / mental form.

Comment: Put another way, suppose I claim that your observations of a "pattern" of "push-back" creating a "hostile environment" mean nothing to me, since my personal experience doesn't fit them. What standard of proof should I be meeting?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I take your word for it that it means nothing to you, in your experience. That's fine, I don't need data. But equally, if you had some complaint I'd look at it, not just say "okay but where is your data?"

Comment: My head is spinning from how meta this answer is… The thing is, okay, now we have *a single anecdote* about how we dismiss experiences. How are we supposed to act on it? If I hadn’t posted this question then there would be no instance of such dismissal? Even referring to the other thread… this is all *in response to trying to talk about the issue.* But that just goes ‘round and ‘round in circles. Can we please talk about some concrete case(s) that initially *spawned* this meta discussion? With enough context to be able to judge the situation?

Comment: @deceze I can give you more anecdotes, but how many is enough? What do you consider "concrete" enough? Or we could discuss this example I already gave you.

Comment: @shogged I think we’re primarily here to talk about SO proper. What I’m looking for are concrete situations on SO proper, illuminated from as many sides as possible, that would present one data point we can try to agree on was or wasn’t problematic. Perhaps a plurality of those would make *data*. The only thing I was trying to say with the *anecdote* provision was that we can’t conclude anything actionable from a *single anecdote*. It needs to be MCVE-enough (have context) to make a data point of which we can collect a few to form data.

Comment: Otherwise the only thing I can personally take away at the moment is that *some people feel something is wrong*, which I’m all sympathetic about, but I have no idea how to act on.

Comment: You are misinterpreting my comment. It is not meant to be the proof complaints are being dismissed because someone belongs to some "minority". On the contrary, it shows people belonging to some "minority" or whatever group tend to interpret all criticism towards them as hostile because they think they have been criticized because  they belong to some group and not because they have done something wrong. And of course, not all people belonging to any group interpret criticism in that way.

Comment: I think it's unfair to paint this post as dismissive. I read this post as 'ok. We have a problem. How big of a problem is it though?'. I agree tone is an issue. I agree quality moderation is seen as harsh and hostile. But a question that seeks the proper data points to be able to frame the issue correctly? I can't see it as dismissive. The blog post makes this look like a systemic issue that is extremely widespread. Even 1example would be a problem. But I think Stack should react differently if it's one example vs if it's 35% of the users of the site. I feel this is what deceze wants clarified

Comment: @Patrice Yup, what you said. ☝️

Comment: I haven't seen single example where people have been mistreated because of their color, gender, race or whatever... on the contrary, in community where I spend most of my time - Delphi developers - you will hear many complains that SO is hostile place and people are afraid to post questions here. But also most (if not all) of those complaints are coming from "privileged" white males.

Comment: @deceze If rene's comment above expresses what you intended to say in the question, you might want to reword that passage. "The plural of anecdote is not data" is typically used when one wants data, and not anecdotes, which seems to be the opposite of what you are looking for. (If this is correct, your post makes sense as it is now, but it is quite easy to misunderstand it.)

Comment: @duplode You're right, done. Which obsoletes this answer though…

Comment: @deceze and shogged: This answer probably can be reworded to be less about this specific question and more about the general reaction on Meta, kinda like the first part of [apaul's answer to the similar-but-derailed question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366853/2751851). In any case, I agree it will be useful to also have answers that are not about Meta.

Comment: @Stargateur Yes, the standard is often arbitrary. Though it doesn't really apply to this question, as discussed above, it is not exactly uncommon for issues raised on Meta to be dismissed with "show me the data" when no one actually knows which kind of data would suffice to confirm there is an issue. Other typical targets of that are posts about bad close votes.

Comment: The number of downvotes on this response is another example of the problem. The real problem is, the people causing the problem don't know they're the problem.

Comment: @barbecue unfortunately a lot of people are triggered by the mere mention of these issues, because they have been primed to assume it means them personally.

Comment: @shogged that's human nature. We're born believing that we're the center of the universe, and we never fully outgrow that. And of course now we can have conversations with random strangers around the world instantly, which makes it even easier to take things personally. Human beings suck at this kind of communication, but we haven't figured that out yet.