# Voting takes me to the main page

Tags: bug, voting, hyperlinks

I have tried to vote on some posts on MSO the last hour, and in some cases it takes me to the Meta Stack Overflow main page. The strange this is that with answers, the one above or under the answer I can't vote on does work.

It seems that sometimes associating the onclick handle goes wrong. Is this a known problem? It might be related to the problem reported a few days back that broke the site navigation.

Last post I have experienced this on was [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366867/993547).

I just had the same issue on SO, where the *show X more comments* link linked to the Jobs page.

Comment: @CodeCaster That seems the case. I haven't had any issues the last hour any more.

Comment: Sorry, too much snark, removed it. :P

Comment: I am not a new user, nor a minority, so it is okay. You can be snarky ;)