# Why is research no longer expected of Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Tim [recently deleted the top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/) to the question asking [how much research is expected of Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for suggesting that people should be doing a lot of research on the grounds that, "it's not advice we want to give to new users".

Why does SO no longer want to advise users that they are expected to do research before asking their questions, and that it's okay to be asking questions that are effectively answered through simple research on the topic, despite it having been a core principle of the site until now, and **very strongly** supported by the community?

Comment: I disagree with the deletion, but this isn't really a fair question. The now top voted question has 'Research your question on Stack Overflow (questions, answers, and comments if you can)' as the second point, right after recommending reading the documentation. It's quite clear (to me), that it was deleted because of the hyperbole

Comment: @Rob is it really a hyperbole? Minus the books, the steps listed in that answer more or less match my workflow.

Comment: @Rob Yes, the top voted answer is now saying that it doesn't matter how readily accessible high quality information is on the topic, not researching it and duplicating it is perfectly fine, as long as it's not on this site.  There are numerous problems with this.  The site not exist to just duplicate information that's already readily accessible.  The search features on the site itself are not nearly as good as those for searching the internet as a whole, so people are less likely to find solutions already on the site.  It doesn't include debugging and troubleshooting in its description.

Comment: @Rob If the hyperbole in the answer was problematic, that can be fixed with editing.  There's no need to delete the whole answer, especially when the other answers are telling people to *not be doing their research*.

Comment: One problem is: first, we had a ~600 score answer saying essentially: _a ton of research_, and a ~250 score answer saying: _some searching on SO and looking at the docs, no debugging and no googling_, and now it suddenly looks like the community agrees it's that second one. Especially since the comments there emphasize it's OK to ask trivial questions where you can easily google the answer, but it's not on SO.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough on that point, there is a slight distinction. But this discrepancy isn't what you're asking here. As to your second point about editing; I fully agree, and mentioned that in the mod room just after I noticed it was deleted

Comment: @Rob Suggesting, that "Do one search on SO" is adequate research is close enough to basically not doing any research that I felt the question was appropriate.  It's basically telling people that the bar for research is now *super* low, to the point that even doing a simple web search is not expected (it's even *discouraged* by the answer, which is just insane to me), that I consider that functionally the same as telling people no research is required.  At least that's the practical effect it has.

Comment: Hilariously from Tim's own answer to [Should moderators be able to delete answers on questions they answer themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365652/691711) *"Moderators are not allowed to remove valid content period; I don't see why the rule needs to be any more complicated than that."*.  The answer was valid.  You could have edited out the "shame" etc or whatever you need to do to help you sleep at night, but the answer should not have been deleted.

Comment: That answer always struck me as somewhat condescending.

Comment: Sorry, this discussion is getting more and more extremist. An over-the-top answer was deleted. Your title equates that to “research is no longer expected”. ***Please stop this***: you are escalating what should be a rational discussion into a shouting match and growing divide that is going to be harder and harder to bridge at this rate. If you can’t keep out the hyperbole, please go take a walk outside to cool off.

Comment: @EJoshuaS How is it condescending?  Why do you believe that the author of that post considers themselves superior to those they're speaking to?

Comment: @zero: Tim Post is not a moderator. And moderators are generally trusted to judge what constitutes “valid”. I don't see how that post you cite applies here even.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, this is not just "some over the top answer was deleted, nothing important here going on at all".  The answer advocating people asking questions here be doing a lot of research is deleted, and one *actively discouraging people from doing research* is promoted in its place.  *That equates to research is no longer expected*.  It's not hyperbole, it's not extremism, it's what those actions are saying, unambiguously.  Calling me an extremist and saying I'm not allowed to voice my options and that I need to leave is not the way to convince me that this isn't a problem.

Comment: @Servy there is already a discussion for that situation. It did not need another one. Your title *is* inflammatory. You can voice your opinion, I didn’t suspend or otherwise gag you, I am just pointing out that you *are* escalating this to hyperbole levels.

Comment: is the XHTML answer still there, it never shows up on Google anymore? that one will be gone soon and that should be the *official* death of the *original* site.

Comment: @Servy At a minimum, it's decidedly sarcastic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I did not notice that there was a discussion on the topic, you're right that two are not needed.  You didn't suspend me, the staff here simply deleted the answer on the FAQ in which the community overwhelmingly voiced it's opinion on the answer, without discussion, after *years*, and are telling me I'm not allowed to discuss it.  Again, I'm not being hyperbolic.  This is what these actions are saying.  You can disagree, but you can't say that I don't believe what I'm saying.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Sure.  Sarcasm is very different from condescension.  It's most assuredly sarcastic.

Comment: @Servy You can discuss it, on the other post. We haven't even given Tim a *chance* to respond yet, so let's not jump to conclusions. If he outright says, 'Yes, I deleted it because we no longer require research', then fine, ask this question again.

Comment: @Servy: I'm *asking* you to stop *escalating* the discussion, not asking you to not discuss it. Note how you are *still doing this*, you are turning my request into something it isn't. That's exactly what I'm asking you *not to do*. It's why I have a very strong impression than you could do with a walk outside to clear your head a bit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You've told me two main things.  You've told me to leave and stop posting, and you've told me to not be hyperbolic. I've told you that *I'm not being hyperbolic*, and that the statements I'm making are not exaggerated, and that telling me to just leave is, well, telling me to leave instead of discussing the issue.  Just telling me that I shouldn't be upset and that this is no big deal and I shouldn't be bothered does not make me any less upset that this is happening.

Comment: @Servy: You are still reading my words **very selectively**. Well, I tried, sorry that you are not hearing what I'm trying to say.

Comment: If we're taking the now top voted answer as doctrine now, I'll go make a few hundred questions by walking through the C Standard and making a question about every detail of the language I can find that isn't explicitly covered by an existing question on Stack Overflow so that "not researching it and duplicating it is perfectly fine, as long as it's not on this site" is no longer a reasonable standard ;)

Comment: @DavyM I feel obligated that SO *tried to get people to do exactly that* with documentation, so they're not the ones you're going to get pushback from in that regard.

Comment: Just to make sure people notice, Undo undeleted the answer about 50 minutes ago.

Comment: @Davy no no, let's continue screaming. Much more productive! Rawr!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - *Well, I tried, sorry that you are not hearing what I'm trying to say.* we hear what you are **doubling down** on **loud and clear**.

Comment: @Yvette I was in the middle of writing an answer to that post you locked, so now I guess the question is at what point is an edit to a community wiki post considered "too much".

Comment: @Dukeling which post? this post

Comment: @YvetteColomb The post this post is talking about - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @Dukeling [I dropped the ball](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386621/3956566) on that. Consider editing the accepted answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not comfortable with your approach here. As far as I can tell this post and OP's comments provide a plausible interpretation of what's going on. You seem to stick with different (also plausible) interpretation, fine. What isn't fine though is casting labels like escalating / extremist - in the context of this discussion it looks like rather unfair attempt to denigrate the competing point of view, and request to stop appears like trying to sweep it under the rug...

Comment: ...also worth noting that appeal to "deleted over-the-top" answer looks quite weak given how it was in the end handled by another moderator and CM (undeleted and polished). I'd rather that you _please stop this_

Comment: @gnat: I am seeing more and more of a Us vs Them division build up here on Meta, where the community is creating more and more of a barrier between themselves and company employees. I am genuinely worried about what comes over to me as a mob mentality, with no room for assuming good intentions any more. I am probably going about this the wrong way to try and dampen the heated spirits however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well yes, I think you are going the wrong way here, in this discussion. I also see the division you're talking about and I understand your worries and your desire to fight it. I even consider joining that fight some time later (as far as I can tell some things seem to be changing). However the way you did it here, it just doesn't feel right, it seems to fail your goal of dampening and looks like adding heat instead

Comment: @MartijnPieters So now that we can see Tim's intentions were exactly as expected here, does that change anything?  Why are we always expected to assume good intentions while SO is constantly assuming the worst of us.  If SO is unwilling to assume good intentions of this community, nor are their actions demonstrating good faith, why must we continue to assume to *over and over*?  I've spent a *long* time assuming good faith on behalf of the company.  But while that good faith can be assumed by default, at some point their actions demonstrate that it's not merited.